# Cannot get mic input in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm just trying to get my audio level and draw some effects, for this basic example, just an ellipse but I cannot get it to work. Following are the code files:

```js
var mic;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  mic.start();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  var vol = mic.getLevel();
  ellipse(100, 100, vol * 200, vol * 200);
}

function touchStarted() {
  getAudioContext().resume()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not able to get my audio input and hence it's not drawing anything. I tried in 2 different browsers and got the following in console, hope it helps in debugging:

Firefox: (In Firefox I get nothing, only this error)

[image]

Chrome: (In Chrome it's just a black canvas and when I speak, the ellipse doesn't show)

[image]

I search some github issues and tried to insert the `touchStarted` function but no luck.

And by the way, I'm using Python Flask server to host it locally for now.

Any solutions, guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are encountering a [known issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/510) in the p5.sound library. AudioIn.getLevel does not work on any non-Chromium based browsers. Additionally if your sketch is not working in Google Chrome it might have to do with how you are hosting it. There are issues loading the p5.sound library when using an insecure connection (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/500) or [this one](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/454) which has a link to a workaround). One thing you could try is accessing your Flask server via `localhost` instead of the loopback address. Your sketch works for me in Chrome when hosted on a secure platform (OpenProcessing.org for example).

Comment: Hi, thank you, the `ngrok` solution worked for Chrome but not for Firefox. So what I did, just downloaded the ngrok from it's official website, installed it and run the command `ngrok http 5000` , so this created a `https` for my `http` localhost flask server. Hope they will soon fix this issue for Firefox and other browsers too.